# Summarise with multiple conditions based on years

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a set of columns based on papers count for each number of year, therefore filtering multiple conditions in dplyr through summarise:

This is my code:

```
words_list <- data %>%
   select(Keywords, year) %>% 
   unnest_tokens(word, Keywords) %>%
   filter(between(year,1990,2017)) %>% 
   group_by(word) %>% 
   summarise(papers_count = n()) %>%
   arrange(desc(papers_count))
```

The code above gives me two columns, 'word' and 'papers_count', I would like to create more columns like papers_count (papers_count1990, papers_count1991, etc..) based on each year between 1990 and 2017.

I Am looking for something like ths:

```
words_list <- data %>%
   select(Keywords, year) %>% 
   unnest_tokens(word, Keywords) %>%
   filter(between(year,1990,2017)) %>% 
   group_by(word) %>% 
   summarise(tot_papers_count = n(), papers_count_1991 = n()year="1991", ...) %>%
   arrange(desc(papers_count))
```

please does anybody have any suggestion?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding `year` to the `group_by`, and then using `spread` to create multiple summary columns.

```
library(tidyr)
words_list_by_year <- data %>%
  select(Keywords, year) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, Keywords) %>%
  filter(between(year,1990,2017)) %>% 
  group_by(year,word) %>% 
  summarise(papers_count = n()) %>%
  spread(year,papers_count,fill=0)
```